# Select Consecutive Year Data using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called <Employee_Bonus_Table> which structure is as below:

| Id | Year | Bonus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017 | 10000 |
| 1 | 2018 | 10000 |
| 1 | 2019 | 20000 |
| 1 | 2020 | 20000 |
| 2 | 2017 | 10000 |
| 2 | 2018 | 10000 |
| 7 | 2013 | 10000 |
| 7 | 2015 | 20000 |
| 7 | 2017 | 10000 |
| 8 | 2010 | 80000 |
| 8 | 2011 | 70000 |
| 8 | 2012 | 80000 |

I want to select ,  and  for those Employee who have received Bonus at least for **3 consecutive years**. So, the output should look like as below:

| Id | Year | Bonus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017 | 10000 |
| 1 | 2018 | 10000 |
| 1 | 2019 | 20000 |
| 1 | 2020 | 20000 |
| 8 | 2010 | 80000 |
| 8 | 2011 | 70000 |
| 8 | 2012 | 80000 |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: This is for #postgresql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  The key observation is that if you subtract an enumerated sequence from the year, the value is constant for consecutive years.

Then you can count within each group and return groups with three or more rows:

```
select id, year, bonus
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by id, year - seqnum) as cnt_group
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by id order by year) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where cnt_group >= 3
order by id, year;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon for quick response, will it be better if I go for <Rank> instead of <Row_Number> just incase we have duplicate values?

Comment: @SDS . . . You can use `rank()` if you have duplicate values.  Your question doesn't mention duplicates, not what to do if you have them.  If you want them counted as a single value, then `rank()` does that.